# How to turn on output buffering in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, output-buffering

how do I turn on output_buffering for every request to my Sf2 app?

I need this to use the the [FirePHPBundle](https://github.com/madiedinro/FirePHPBundle), but I would prefer to have it application-wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to do this is in AppKernel's `init` method where the framework also registers various error handlers and debug flags:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
...
public function init() 
{
    parent::init(); //do not forget to call this    

    if ($this->debug) {
        ob_start(); 
    }
}
}
```

This of course will call ob_start only in a development environment

You need not to worry about calling `ob_start` here because as the php manual states:

> Output buffers are stackable, that is, you may call ob_start() while another ob_start() is active. Just make sure that you call ob_end_flush() the appropriate number of times. If multiple output callback functions are active, output is being filtered sequentially through each of them in nesting order.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like i actually needed to call ob_end_flush after the firephp logging, otherwise it doesn't show :(